# Add CSS rule via jQuery for future created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a somewhat unusual issue. I've done something like this many times:

```
$('#selector').css('color','#00f');
```

My problem is that I create a `<div id="selector">`, and I call the command above and it works fine.

Now, on another event, later, I remove that element from the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and add it again at a later time with the same id. This element now doesn't have `color:#00f`.

Is there a way that I can add a rule in CSS, such that it will affect items that are created in the future with that same `id`/`class`? I like [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), but anything with plain JavaScript would be fine as well.

It has to be dynamic, and I don't know the classes to put in a CSS file.  Also, I plan on changing a single attribute a few different times through the course of the application. For example, setting the `color` to `black`, to `blue`, to `red`, and back to `black`.

---

I went with the answer from **@lucassp**, and this is what I ended up with:

```
function toggleIcon(elem, classname)
{
    if($(elem).attr('src')=='img/checkbox_checked.gif')
    {
        $(elem).attr('src', 'img/checkbox_unchecked.gif')
        //$('.'+classname).hide();//this was the old line that I removed
        $('html > head').append($('<style>.'+classname+' { display:none; }</style>'));
    }
    else
    {
        $(elem).attr('src', 'img/checkbox_checked.gif')
        //$('.'+classname).show();//this was the old line that I removed
        $('html > head').append($('<style>.'+classname+' { display:block; }</style>'));
    }
}
```

I also want to say that **@Nelson** is probably the most "correct", though it would require more work to go into application code that always works fine, and that's not effort I want to spend at the moment.

If I had to rewrite this (or write something similar) in the future, I would look into `detach()`.

Comment: `.css()` sets style attribute of the `$('#selector')`. It does not create a css rule.

Comment: I know that, that's exactly what I'm asking, I want to create a rule, not just adjust an attribute

Comment: I was just pointing it out as you seemed to be surprised with the result of `.css()` method. The responses are giving you some direction how to handle this.

Comment: No, I'm not surprised by it. I'm quite familiar with `css()`, and I know it just edits the matched DOM elements and doesn't make a permanent rule

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This should work:

```
var style = $('<style>.class { background-color: blue; }</style>');
$('html > head').append(style);
```

Comment: Slightly cheaper js: $('<style>.class { background: blue; }</style>').appendTo('head'); http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/LNYaR/

Comment: how would you remove that style in the head if needed later?

Comment: @Felipe $("style").replaceWith might help rerender css rules.

Comment: This doesn't work for changing a `max-height` style (it's been set to 400px in CSS but I want to change it to 300px). Is there any workaround?

Comment: @KeirSimmons add !important to the rule to override it (as long as max-height was not applied inline with matching priority)

Comment: @Philll_t give the style an id e.g  $('<style id="customstyle">.class { background: blue; }</style>').appendTo('head'); $("#customstyle").remove();

Comment: If this doesn't work for someone, see my answer which has "!important " added.

Answer (score 12):

When you plan to remove elements from the DOM to re-insert them later, then use [**.detach()**](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of `.remove()`.

Using `.detach()` will preserve your CSS when re-inserting later. From the documentation:

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach()
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

Comment: You first detach and save the element in a variable: `var p = $("#myelement").detach();` then later you can insert your element again with `$('#somediv').append(p);`  or the equivalent `p.appendTo('#somediv');`

Answer (score 8):

In case this style section suppose to be changed several times, you can set in the html file a style tag with id:

```
<style id="myStyleTag">
</style>
```

then you can refer it with js, edit or remove content like:

```
var style = $('#myStyleTag');
styl.html('.class { background-color: blue; }');
```

in this way the style section will not become bigger if you change it several times because you don't just append it to the head but edit it as needed.

Comment: @kokociel please do not make changes to other authors' code. If you think the code is wrong or has a typo in it, leave a comment!

Comment: Hmm isn't this asserting that we'd be undermining the author's intent? That maybe an author wanted to write code with subtle mistakes? I wonder what purpose the 3rd-party editing functionality is supposed to offer, if not for the correction of minor mistakes.

Answer (score 7):

Here is some JavaScript code I wrote before to let me add, remove and edit CSS:

```
function CSS(sheet) {

    if (sheet.constructor.name === 'CSSStyleSheet' )
        this.sheet = sheet;
    else if (sheet.constructor.name === 'HTMLStyleElement')
        this.sheet = sheet.sheet;
    else
        throw new TypeError(sheet + ' is not a StyleSheet');
}

CSS.prototype = {
    constructor: CSS,
    add: function( cssText ) {
        return this.sheet.insertRule(cssText, this.sheet.cssRules.length);
    },
    del: function(index) {
        return this.sheet.deleteRule(index);
    },
    edit: function( index, cssText) {
        var i;
        if( index < 0 )
            index = 0;
        if( index >= this.sheet.cssRules.length )
            return this.add(cssText);
        i = this.sheet.insertRule(cssText, index);
        if (i === index)
            this.sheet.deleteRule(i + 1);
        return i;
    }
};
```

And then if a new stylesheet is required, construct as

```
var myCss = new CSS(document.head.appendChild( document.createElement('style')));
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to add a class:

```
.selected {
    color : #00f ;
}

$('#elemId').addClass('selected')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [livequery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery).

```
$('#selector').livequery(function() { $(this).css('color', '#00f'); });
```

Comment: why would this need a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question with a chosen answer, but adding dynamic CSS to accomplish the goal is not necessary and is likely sending people in the wrong direction.

If you want to dynamically set styles on an element using jQuery, it is best to use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` with classes that affect the required style.

Given the function in the question:

```
function toggleIcon(elem, classname)
    {
      if($(elem).attr('src')=='img/checkbox_checked.gif')
    {
        $(elem).attr('src', 'img/checkbox_unchecked.gif');
        $("." + classname).addClass("hidden");
    }
    else
    {
        $(elem).attr('src', 'img/checkbox_checked.gif');
        $("." + classname).removeClass("hidden");
    }
}
```

And then just add this to your CSS:

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

This would also work to change color, as also mentioned in the question:

```
.checkbox-red {color: red;}
.checkbox-blue {color: blue;}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the accepted answer. But if you wanted to do this in just one line, you could do something like this:

```
$('<style>').append('.'+classname+'{display:none}').appendTo('head')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS rule in your CSS file

```
.yourclass{
    color: #00f;
}
```

Add `yourclass` whenever you're creating the element:

```
$("#selector").addClass("yourclass");
```

Comment: it has to be dynamic, I don't know the classes to put there

Comment: I don't have control of adding classes to the element when it's created

Answer (score 0):

Just use a class, for example:

CSS:

```
.setcolor { color: #fff; }
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#selector').addClass('setcolor');
```

Then remove it when needed:

```
$('#selector').removeClass('setcolor');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a style element in your document, you can just add another rule to it with vanilla js:

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule('#selector', 'color: #00f');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var style = $('<style>.class { background-color: blue !important; }</style>');
$('html > head').append(style);
```