# Replacing Specific color code in css using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to replace #789034 code to another code like #456780 where ever it finds in main.css using jquery

I am having a main.css file something like below :

```
.common-color
{
  color:#789034;
}

.new-cls
{
  border-color:#789034;
  height:300px;
}

.awesome-one
{
  background-color:#789034;
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
}
```

I want to replace #789034 code to another code like #456780 where ever it finds in main.css using jquery like :

```
$(each where code=#789034)
{
  set code: #456780;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should have a single class having `color: #789034;` and add this class to all the elements where this color is required. And then it'll be easy to change color using jQuery: `$('.myClass').css('color', '#456780');`

Comment: its not practically possible, because i am using it on server properties, like border-color:#789034- Think i made a common color class for the code how to pass that class for border color--like 1px solid-- .comon-color.

Comment: means ?? actually i clearly said i want to replace a specific color code to other on all places in one go using jquery- Your code selecting attribute, i want only code code to new color code

Comment: Really sorry, if i was rude - that was not my intention, really sorry,yes, i it was close and thanks a lot, just it has extra thing i.e attribute, i don't want attribute as parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084411/modify-css-rules-with-javascript-or-jquery (which doesn't have an accepted answer yet either)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a solution which I'll explain step-by-step.

First, call `colorReplace("#789034", "#456780");`. The first value is the target color, and the second is the replacement color.

Inside it, `$('*').map(function(i, el) {` will select all tags in the DOM tree. For each element, its `getComputedStyle(el)` styles array is returned. You can customize the selector for faster processing (e.g. `$('div').map(function(i, el)) {`).

All style attributes containing "color" (e.g. `background-color`, `-moz-outline-color`, etc.), it will be checked if the color value is equal to your target color. If so, it will be replaced with the target color.

Colors are returned like `rgba(0,0,0,0)` or `rgb(0,0,0)`, not like `#FFFFFF`, so a quick conversion is done from rgb to hex for the comparison. That uses the internal `rgb2hex()` function.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

---

```js
function colorReplace(findHexColor, replaceWith) {
  // Convert rgb color strings to hex
  // REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627747/1938889
  function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    if (/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test(rgb)) return rgb;
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
      return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
  }

  // Select and run a map function on every tag
  $('*').map(function(i, el) {
    // Get the computed styles of each tag
    var styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);

    // Go through each computed style and search for "color"
    Object.keys(styles).reduce(function(acc, k) {
      var name = styles[k];
      var value = styles.getPropertyValue(name);
      if (value !== null && name.indexOf("color") >= 0) {
        // Convert the rgb color to hex and compare with the target color
        if (value.indexOf("rgb(") >= 0 && rgb2hex(value) === findHexColor) {
          // Replace the color on this found color attribute
          $(el).css(name, replaceWith);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

// Call like this for each color attribute you want to replace
colorReplace("#789034", "#456780");
```

```css
.common-color {
  color: #789034;
}
.new-cls {
  border-color: #789034;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.awesome-one {
  background-color: #789034;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="common-color">color</div>
<div class="new-cls">border-color</div>
<div class="awesome-one">background-color</div>
```

Comment: Where is it getting CSS rules from?  `getComputedStyle`?

Comment: Yes, `getComputedStyle` will return an impressive array of computed styles. This solution filters on those styles which contain "color", then a comparison is performed, and a color replacement if needed

Comment: @Drakes How to replace with if css is look like

color: #efefef !important;

Comment: You might be interested to know that (after 4 years) this answer is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380430/is-there-any-recourse-after-a-dispute-that-has-already-been-decided)

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Sure, I think one should have the possibility to defend himself

Answer (score 2):

Why, its elementary, dear Watson. Just grab all possible style-keys, check if they contain the word color, then replace all occurrences of the color with the new one using a complex regex system.

```js
// gathers all style "keys" like height, width, color, etc
var keys = Object.values(window.getComputedStyle($('html').get(0)));
// removes any style keys which are not color related
var filteredKeys = keys.filter(function (key){return key.indexOf('color') > -1});
// parses the hex string of the color to be replaced into its R, G, and B parts and stores them in an array
var colors = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec("#789034").splice(1,3); 
// converts these hex strings to decimal and combines them into a "rgb(#, #, #)" formatted color string
var rgb = 'rgb(' + colors.map(function (color){return parseInt(color, 16)}).join(', ') + ')';
// go through each element in the page
$("*").each(function (index, element) {
    // go through each color-related style "key"
    filteredKeys.forEach(function(key) {
        // if the element's value for this key matches the color to be replaced...
        if ($(element).css(key) == rgb) {
            // ...replace that color with the replacement color
            $(element).css(key, "#456780");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
.common-color {
    color:#789034;
}
.new-cls {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#789034;
}
.awesome-one {
    background-color:#789034;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="common-color">hello</div>
<p class="new-cls">cool</p>
<div class="awesome-one"></div>
```

**EDIT:**

Or, if you would rather, here is a simple function to use. Color 1 will be replaced by color 2:

```
function replaceColor(color1, color2) {
    var keys = Object.values(window.getComputedStyle($('html').get(0)));
    var filteredKeys = keys.filter(function (key){return key.indexOf('color') > -1});
    var colors = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(color1).splice(1,3); 
    var rgb = 'rgb(' + colors.map(function (color){return parseInt(color, 16)}).join(', ') + ')';
    $("*").each(function (index, element) {
        filteredKeys.forEach(function(key) {
            if ($(element).css(key) == rgb) {
                $(element).css(key, color2);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this functionality by using CSS variables. Define a variable in your main.css file.

```
:root {   
    --color1: #789034; 
}
```

and use this variable instead of color code.

```
.common-color
{
  color: var(--color1);
}
```

Now you can change the color by implementing the following function through passing new color in the parameter.

```
function ChangeColor1(newColor)
{
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color1',newColor);
}
```

Comment: This was the best and consistent answer for me. In fact, it avoid many errors the other methods have.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the following:

Put your stylesheet inline into the document, wrapped by a style tag:

```
<style id="myStyles" type="text/css"> /* all your css here */ </style>
```

Now you can probably get all the contents of this via

```
let myCss = document.getElementById('myStyles').innerHTML;
```

Then go ahead and do the replacement magic:

```
myCSS = myCSS.replace(/#789034/g, "#456780");
```

And in a last, hopeful effort, put it back in the DOM:

```
document.getElementById('myStyles').innerHTML = myCss;
```

But even if this should work, it seems to me very probable that you are bringing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score -2):

you might consider changing it with jquery.

```
$(function() {
  $('.awesome-one').hover( function(){
     $(this).css('background-color', '#789034');
  },
  function(){
     $(this).css('background-color', '#456780');
  });
});
```

Comment: your code is just for background, i clearly mentioned that it should change at all place where it found #789034 to this #456780- Thanks