# Cannot apply style to anchor tag when assigning to innerHTML

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm assigning a string that contains anchor tags to an element's innerHTML. I need to style these, however, I am not sure how to do so. Here's an example using `Polymer.dom` and `updateStyles` as suggested by this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000446/applying-styles-to-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml-in-polymer):

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'x-foo',
  properties: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      value: '<a href="//google.com">Hello</a>',
      observer: 'setValue'
    }
  },
  
  setValue: function() {
    Polymer.dom(this).innerHTML = this.value;
    this.updateStyles();
  }
});
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:1.4.0/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">


<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <style>
    a {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<x-foo></x-foo>
```

And here's a link to the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cbelden/xamfhe52/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `updateStyles()`. Your `dom-module` style should be using [`::content`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#styling-distributed-children-content) to target the distributed nodes:

```
<style>
  ::content a {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {

  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      value: {
        type: String,
        value: '<a href="//google.com">Hello</a>',
        observer: 'setValue'
      }
    },

    setValue: function() {
      Polymer.dom(this).innerHTML = this.value;
      //this.updateStyles(); // not needed
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:1.4.0/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">


<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <style>
    ::content a {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<x-foo></x-foo>
```